# Initialize instance with mother class attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am working with fits files that I read with fits.open() from the astropy lib. I get a hdu (header data unit), which is an instance of astropy.io.fits.hdu.image.PrimaryHDU.

Now, for a specific project, I want to work on the data in this hdu, by writing specific methods. A good way on doing it, I thought, is writing my own class that would be a subclass of PrimaryHDU. My new object would have all the attributes and methods of the PrimaryHDU instance, plus attributes and methods that I will write. But I cannot get it to work properly. How can my new object get all the attributes and method of the parent object? The closest I have come to is with the following piece of code (with, for example, a new method call "subtract"):

```
from astropy.io.fits.hdu.image import PrimaryHDU

class MyHDU(PrimaryHDU):

    def __init__(self, hdu):
        PrimaryHDU.__init__(self, data=hdu.data, header=hdu.header)

    def subtract(self, val):
        self.data = self.data - val
```

It is kind of ok, but I can see that my new object doesn't have all the attributes set to the same value as the original object (hdu).... which seems normal, when I look at my code actually... but how can I initialize my new object with all the attribute of the parent object? And am I correct to make my new class inherit from the PrimaryHDU class?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I initialize my new object with all the attribute of the parent object?

You can't. You don't inherit from an instance (ie object), you inherit from a class.

What you should be doing is pass all the arguments you need in order to init both the parent and the subclass. In the child class's `__init__` method call `super().__init__` (the `__init__` method of the parent class) and then initialize the rest of the child class:

```
from astropy.io.fits.hdu.image import PrimaryHDU

class MyHDU(PrimaryHDU):

    def __init__(self, args_to_init_PrimaryHDU_obj, hdu):
        super().__init__(args_to_init_PrimaryHDU_obj)
        # if using Python 2 the above line should be
        # super(PrimaryHDU, self).__init__(args_to_init_PrimaryHDU_obj)
        self.data = hdu.data
        self.header = hdu.header

    def subtract(self, val):
        self.data = self.data - val
```

Comment: sure, ok that makes sense. I was confusing the object and the class indeed. Thanks. But is: super(PrimaryHDU, self).__init__(args_to_init_PrimaryHDU_obj) different from:  PrimaryHDU.__init__(args_to_init_PrimaryHDU_obj) ?

Comment: @samR It depends on the version of Python you are using, and if using Python 2 it depends whether or not `PrimaryHDU` is an old-style or a new-style class.